# How to create by group in proc gplot

Tags: sas

I want to create multiple plots by category. Currently my code is as follows:

```
proc gplot data=data;
     plot (a b)*week
     *by category;
     /vaxis=axis3 haxis=axis3 legend=legend1 overlay skipmiss;
     title font='HELVETICA' height=1.2 "Volumes"; 
run;
```

but this includes all the categories. How do I create distinct charts for different categories? Also the chart here is a scatter plot. How do I create a line chart?

Comment: I am not too familiar with proc gplot, but I think proc sgpanel or one of the other sg-graphic procs may do what you are looking for.

Comment: What version of SAS do you have?  Are you amenable to SGPLOT?

Answer (score 0):

A fellow SAS 9.1.x user? Assuming that you require a gplot-based example:

```
proc summary data = sashelp.class nway;
    var height;
    class sex age;
    output out = class mean=;
run;

symbol1 interpol = join;

proc gplot data = class;
    by sex;
    plot height * age;
    run;
quit;
```

Here proc summary conveniently produces a sorted output dataset without any duplicate y-values, allowing gplot to produce a pair of reasonable line charts via the by statement. I'm sure there are much nicer-looking alternatives via proc sgplot if you have a more recent version of SAS, but some of us have to make do with gplot.